# Automatically resize input according to button size?

Tags: html, css

I have an `input` and a `button` in the same div, and want them to be in a single line without any gap in between, regardless of screen size, but cannot get that to happen. The button seems to have a horizontal padding, although I set both `padding` and `margin` to `none`, so % wouldn't be a solution. Also, I would like the button to wrap around its contents, so even if it could work, it wouldn't be the greatest solution. Is there a way to set the location and size of the button and resize the input accordingly with CSS? Or is some JavaScript needed to do this?

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Current Output:

[image: Gap in button][image: Button going to the next line]

Current code (CSS is insignificant, as it doesn't work)

```css
.chatinp {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  size: fixed;
  height: auto;
  border-top: solid;
}

#CHAT {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}

#SEND {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #090;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatinp">
  <input type="text" name="CHAT" id="CHAT">
  <button name="SEND", id="SEND">SEND</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should go look into `flexbox`.

Comment: How will the final output looks like ? Can you draw a picture or something please

Comment: @CBroe it will be better to use `grid` ryt? so that we can specify the required space for each item in it.

Comment: @SandrinJoy grid is basically the two-dimensional version, of what flexbox already offers for one single direction. But the problem here is only in one direction, the width; height does not come into play. So flexbox can do the job as well here.

Comment: thanks for this info @CBroe ✌

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several tools to achieve that :

- [CSS property `float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) (example below)

  - will run even on old browser
  - doesn't fit for complex use (in your case, that fine)
- [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)
- [CSS Flex element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

### Float Example

```css
.chatinp {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

#CHAT, #SEND{
  box-sizing: border-box; /* permit the use of border and padding without overstepping the width */
  height: 100%; /* use all of the avaible height given by the parent */
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
  position: relative; /* needed for float */
  float: left; /* make element align from left to right, then top to bottom */
}

#CHAT {
  width: 85%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}

#SEND {
  width: 15%;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatinp">
  <input type="text" name="CHAT" id="CHAT">
  <button name="SEND" id="SEND">SEND</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use **[flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** if I understood your demand.

I added `display: flex` on parent container (`.chatnip`) and `flex : <value>` on child elements to tell them how much space they should take.

There's no gap between the boxes.

```css
.chatinp {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  size: fixed;
  height: auto;
  border-top: solid;
  display: flex
}

#CHAT {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  color: white;
  flex: 9;
}

#SEND {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #090;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  color: white;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatinp">
  <input type="text" name="CHAT" id="CHAT">
  <button name="SEND", id="SEND">SEND</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making use of flexbox, try to make the most advantage of it. For `chatinp` class use `display: flex` and for `#CHAT` use `flex: 1` if needed add a width for `#SEND`

```css
.chatinp {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: solid;
  display: flex;
}

#CHAT {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* bottom: 0; */
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 95%; */
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
  flex: 1;
}

#SEND {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* bottom: 0; */
  /* right: 0; */
  /* height: 100%; */
  /* width: 10%; */
  background-color: #090;
  border: solid 1px #fff;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatinp">
  <input type="text" name="CHAT" id="CHAT" />
  <button name="SEND" id="SEND">SEND</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I prefer to use `grid` where you can specify how much portion and number of elements to be placed in a single row**

```css
div{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:80vw auto;/*auto auto , if you don't need any specific space for the items*/
}
```

```html
<div class="chatinp">
  <input type="text" name="CHAT" id="CHAT">
  <button name="SEND", id="SEND">SEND</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add these to your css: (and get rid of height: 100%; from #CHAT)

```
.chatinp {
  display: flex;
}

#CHAT {
  height: auto;
}
```